# Show that if $F(x)$ is a polynomial over $K$, then $F(A)=0$ if and only if $F(T_A)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be the space of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $K$. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Let $T_A: V\to V$ be the linear transformation given by $T_A(B)=AB$.
>
> Show that if $F(x)$ is a polynomial over $K$, then $F(A)=0$ if and only if $F(T_A)=0$.

---

We can easily show that if $F(T_A)=0$, then $F(A)=0$ since we can consider $F(A)=F(T_A(I))=0$.

---

However, the converse I don't think is correct. Let's say we are over $\mathbb R$.

If we have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\2&0\end{pmatrix}$, and the polynomial $F(x)=(x-2)(x+2)(x+3)$, then $F(A)=0$ since $\mu_A(x) \mid F(x)$, but if we let $B=\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\1&3\end{pmatrix}$, then $F(AB)\ne 0$. So, it cannot be the case that $F(T_A)=0$.

**Is this correct or am I missing something here?**

Comment: Use your $F(x)$ as example, $F(\mathcal T _{\boldsymbol A}) = (\mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A} - 2\mathcal I)(\mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A} +2\mathcal I)(\mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A} + 3\mathcal I)$, then $F(\mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A}) \colon \boldsymbol B \mapsto (\boldsymbol A^3 + 3\boldsymbol A^2 -4\boldsymbol A - 12 \boldsymbol I)\boldsymbol B $.

Comment: So, if we have $f(x)=x^2$, then is $f(T_A)=(T_A)^2$ or is $f(T_A)=T^2_A$?

Comment: Same thing. These both mean to apply $\mathcal T_{\mathcal A}$ twice to some $\boldsymbol B \in V$.

Comment: Well, if I see $(T_A)^2$, then I think we should have $(T_A(B))^2=(AB)^2$, which is not the same as $A^2B$.

Comment: No. That's not the meaning for a polynomial $F(x)$ of $\mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A}$. For example, for $F(x^2+x +1), $We define $F(\mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A})$ to be the linear transformation $\mathcal T^2 + \mathcal T + \mathcal I$, which takes $\boldsymbol B$ to $(\boldsymbol {A^2 + A + I})\boldsymbol B$.

Comment: Or, we could say $F(\mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A}) \boldsymbol B$ does not mean $(F \circ \mathcal T_{\boldsymbol A}) (\boldsymbol B)$ as a composition of two functions.

Comment: @xbh I forgot that's how polynomial over an algebra was defined. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark that $X^n(T_A)(B)=(T_A)^n(B)=A^nB$, thus $P(T_A)(B)=P(A)B$.

Comment: What is $X^n$??

Comment: It is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: So, it is not $(AB)^n$